# Submit WatchKit Provisioning Error

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, watchkit

Currently i try to submit a new app to the store with Xcode 6.2
This App includes a WatchKit Extension.
All works fine, but all the time i get one error while submit/validate.

[image]

In iTunes Connect i created a App with the BundleID etc
Also i if check my developer portal there is a provisioning profile with the name "Datulator WatchKit Extension".

Anyone can explain me what i m doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. Here is the solution that worked for me.

Technical Q&A QA1830
The beta-reports-active Entitlement
Q:  How do I resolve the "beta-reports-active" code signing error?
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1830/_index.html

I had to regenerate the "Distribution" Provisioning Profile that I was using to submit my entire app, before I included the WatchKit extension. Specifically, these steps fixed my problem:

I logged onto the developer.apple.com, selected "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".

1. On the Certs IDs & Profiles website > Provisioning Profiles page, click the App Store profile.
2. Click 'Edit'
3. Click 'Generate'

If you have further problems with provisioning. Try this link:

Technical Q&A QA1814
Setting up Xcode to automatically manage your provisioning profiles
Q:  How do I configure my Xcode project to use automatic provisioning?
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1814/_index.html

Comment: Wich Profil did you recreated the .watchkit or the "normal one"? can you add some more information?

As i did try to regenerate it, recreate etc

Comment: I had to regenerate the "Distribution" Provisioning Profile that I was using
to submit my entire app, before I included the WatchKit extension. So I guess that means the "normal one".

Specifically, these steps fixed my problem:

I logged onto the developer.apple.com, selected "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".

1. On the Certs IDs & Profiles website > Provisioning Profiles page, click the App Store profile.
2. Click 'Edit'
3. Click 'Generate'

Comment: Strange... but worked :) thanks... can't give you +1  -.- can you edit your answere once so i can resubmit

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad this worked for you. I have edited my answer to include more details.

Comment: The **Technical Q&A QA1814** with link above solved it all for me. I already had the provisioning profiles and certificates set up for a "normal" iOS app. Now I needed to get it to work with Watchkit apps, after many hours of trouble I followed the routes in the QA1814 article and voila!! Xcode solved everything for me. Didn't need to change/resolve/update anything in Member Center etc.