# No matching provisioning profiles found for WatchKit extension when submitting to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, watchkit

I'm using xcode 6.3

xcode had created a provisioning profile "xxx.xxx.xxx.watchkitextension" automatically, in the code signing of watchkit extension target, I've tried choosing this profile or leaving it Automatic, they all giving me this error "Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets" when I submit it to App Store.

[image]

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Watchkit Extension - No matchin provisioning profiles found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816339/watchkit-extension-no-matchin-provisioning-profiles-found)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem looks similar to this question.
[Submit WatchKit Provisioning Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479139/submit-watchkit-provisioning-error)

I had the same problem. Here is the solution that worked for me.

Technical Q&A QA1830 The beta-reports-active Entitlement Q: How do I resolve the "beta-reports-active" code signing error? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1830/_index.html

I had to regenerate the "Distribution" Provisioning Profile that I was using to submit my entire app, before I included the WatchKit extension. Specifically, these steps fixed my problem:

I logged onto developer.apple.com, selected "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".

1. On the Certs IDs & Profiles website > Provisioning Profiles page, click the App Store profile.
2. Click 'Edit'
3. Click 'Generate'

Comment: Thanks, I searched before by didn't find that question.

Answer (score 2):

Following steps help me out:
1.Make sure "App Groups" in Capabilities page in Container target and Extension target.

2.Goto Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > YOUR_ACCOUNT > View Details ..., CTRL+Click one of the Profiles and open in Finder. Move all Profiles to Trash.

3.Open "App Groups" in Container target and Extension target. Xcode will generate two profiles for you, just like iOSTeam Provisioning Profile: YOURAPPID  and iOSTeam Provisioning Profile: YOURAPPID.watchkitextension.
(Make sure your container target and WatchKit App target choose the first one as PP,and your extension target choose the second one).

4.If everything goes well, you can do whatever build, run and submit.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to revoke my certificates (preferences -> accounts). After that XCode offered to recreate them. All fine now. Not sure whether this has unwanted side effects as previous certificates are now invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message trying to submit an update to a Watch App that was previously rejected.  Since i had previously uploaded, I did not see this error.  I used a support incident to get help after exhausting all paths.

I got a response in just 1 or 2 business days -- which at first annoyed me. They said i needed to reset everything to use "team provisioning profiles" and all would be fine. I am an individual developer, so my "team profile" is just mine... but I did walk through all the steps and ta-da, much to my surprise, everything worked and the errors went away. Nothing really to do with any of the application specific or other provisioning profiles i had -- i must have changed a "signing identity" somewhere so Xcode's automatic resolution / fix up did not work.

Apple's message was: 
CONVERTING TO TEAM BASED CODE SIGNING

Team-based signing should be used in Xcode 5 and later: it’s the recommended workflow and is what’s covered in App Distribution Guide. Team based code signing requires resetting of all code signing settings in each targets build settings to their defaults. Xcode will no longer use the Code Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile build settings, but instead choose the best combination of signing identities and provisioning profile for the scheme being built.

[Technical Q&A QA1814 - Setting up Xcode to automatically manage your provisioning profiles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1814/_index.html/Title)

Which is quite clear and solved all my problems.