# Issue AppSubmit None of valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements Watchkit

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I have 2 days around trying to solve this problem.
When i try to submit my app, I have two issues

`No matching provisioning profiles found for "Applications/myapp.app
None of valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: beta-reports-active, com.apple.security.application-groups.`

And same in WatchKit Extension.appex

The bundles are `com.mycompany.myapp` and `com.mycompany.myapp.watchkitapp`

The app-group is active in my app and Apple Watch app with `group.com.mycompany.myapp` In the .Entitlements  `com.apple.security.application-groups` have item 0 with my app group

Any idea with the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem looks similar to this question.

[No matching provisioning profiles found for WatchKit extension when submitting to App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544427/no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found-for-watchkit-extension-when-submitting-t)

and this question:

[Submit WatchKit Provisioning Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479139/submit-watchkit-provisioning-error)

I had the same problem. Here is the solution that worked for me.

Technical Q&A QA1830 The beta-reports-active Entitlement Q: How do I resolve the "beta-reports-active" code signing error? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1830/_index.html

I had to regenerate the "Distribution" Provisioning Profile that I was using to submit my entire app, before I included the WatchKit extension. Specifically, these steps fixed my problem:

I logged onto developer.apple.com, selected "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".

1. On the Certs IDs & Profiles website > Provisioning Profiles page, click the App Store profile.
2. Click 'Edit'
3. Click 'Generate'

[image: Regenerate Provisioning Profile]

Comment: Thank you very much, i deleted all the code singing entitlements, at the moment of submit not show an error  but does not works, i'll have to cancel and try this, thanks.

Comment: thank you for the clear screenshot, showing 'distribution' highlighted.  in my case, xcode auto created provisioning profile for development, but not distribution.  i manually added the distribution profile, and can submit app without error :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in XCode 7. but when i use latest version of XCode (9) then i could successfully submit the build.