# watchOS Provisioning Error

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, xcode7, watchos-2

I am getting the following error in Xcode 7 GM while trying to submit an app with a native watchOS App.

[image: screenshot of problem]

I have 3 provisioning profiles installed:

-com.devname.appname

-com.devname.appname.watchkitapp

-com.devname.appname.watchkitapp.watchkitextension

I have tried the following questions, but none of the solutions seem to work
[Submit WatchKit Provisioning Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479139/submit-watchkit-provisioning-error), [Watchkit Extension - No matching provisioning profiles found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816339/watchkit-extension-no-matchin-provisioning-profiles-found), [No matching provisioning profiles found for WatchKit extension when submitting to App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544427/no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found-for-watchkit-extension-when-submitting-t) and others, however they all appear to be before watchOS Extensions were bundled inside watchOS Apps.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly this is a bug with Xcode 7.0's automatic selection of provisioning profiles.

I solved this problem by setting each "release" provisioning profile at the target level:

[image: code signing settings]

Note: the default setting is "Automatic"